# How Do I Create Custom HAML "Mixins" Like Pug/Jade

Tags: pug, haml, helper

I'm new to both HAML and Ruby.  I've used Pug/Jade to compile HTML files before and I'm trying to find a way  to mimic its mixin functionality in HAML.

I'm thinking the helpers or controllers are the way to go but I'm not sure how to get them working.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

With partials,

_my_partial.html.haml

```
#my_mixin.myclass(style="background:#{background}" )
  %hr
  %h2= text
  %p= text1
```

then in the view

```
= render _my_partial, :background =>'img.png', :text => 'Lorem', :text1 => 'Ipsum...'
= render _my_partial, :background =>'img1.png', :text => 'Lorem2', :text1 => 'Ipsum3...'
```

Comment: It appears like this is a Rails/Ruby solution rather than a Haml one. Looks like it could help Rails folks, but not all of Haml users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way. Unfortunately, Haml hasn't included a way to achieve that for the moment.

The closest you can get would be to define a function in your host programming language or reusing partials (see DFOXpro's answer).

You might find the Haml helper [`capture_haml(*args){ |args| ... }`](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Helpers.html#capture_haml-instance_method) helpful:

> Captures the result of a block of Haml code, gets rid of the excess indentation, and returns it as a string. For example, after the following,
>
> ```
> .foo
>   - foo = capture_haml(13) do |a|
>     %p= a
> ```
>
> the local variable foo would be assigned to `"<p>13</p>\n"`.